# Layout issue on multiple devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

As we know we can create a single layout for all type of devices by using size in dp.  i have created a xml with dp but it is displaying different on every other device like 7' , 10' tab, 5.4, 5.1 3.7 etc.

i have placed file in "layout"  folder and now to support all these device i have to create different layout folder for all devices and it is tough to maintain, even i have created a hdpi,xhdpi etc as well but still lots of layout is need to create. please find below xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:id="@+id/ans4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_orange"
tools:context="com.kids.kidsmath.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mathCalculation"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_shape"
    android:onClick="openMa"
    android:text="Play "
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/learnCounting"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mathCalculation"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mathCalculation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mathCalculation"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_shape"
    android:onClick="openL"
    android:text="Lg"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/greatersmaller"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/learnCounting"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/learnCounting"
    android:layout_below="@+id/learnCounting"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_shape"
    android:onClick="openS"
    android:text="Gr"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

please help me if i m doing wrong in this xml. also do we need to define different xml for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there's a little misunderstanding what density-independent-pixel really means. So I'll try to explain it in a somewhat unconventional way:

Let's take one of your buttons, for example. You defined `android:layout_width="250dp"`. So your button will have the same width on every 5" device, no matter what's the resolution. It won't be the same width on a 7" or 10" in relation to the actually available width.
To make things a little bit clearer here are the dp-resolutions of the Nexus 5, 7 and 10 compared to the px-resolutions.

```
Nexus 5   1920x1080px   640x360dp
Nexus 7   1920x1200px   960x600dp
Nexus 10  2560x1600px   1280x800dp
```

**Note:** As you can see the resolution of the N5 and N7 is almost identical though the height in dp is still alot different. `(640dp vs 960dp)` That's because of the density difference `(xxhdpi vs xhdpi)`.

So what can you do to optimize the layout for a broad range of devices? Well, as you already said, a layout-folder for all devices is tough to maintain especially if you want to change something in the layout later on. That's why you should use *dimension files*. [(Link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

I'll try to explain it with the *textSize*. 
So let's say we defined the textSize to be `18sp`. This is fairly large on a smartphone. On a 7" tablet it's still ok but on a 10" tablet it's pretty small. So instead of creating a layout-file for all three devices we define a dimension reference. 
First of all you need to create a `dimens.xml` in your values-folder and define the dimension afterwards, for example:

```
<dimen name="my_text_size">18sp</dimen>
```

In your layout-file you reference the size-value like this:

```
android:textSize="@dimension/my_text_size"
```

In order to adapt the textSize for different devices you create a `values-sw600dp` (used by the Nexus 7) and a `values-sw720dp` (used by the Nexus 10) folder. Then you copy the `dimens.xml` to both folders and change the value to e.g. `22sp` (@sw600dp) and `26sp` (@720dp). Now you're layout is kinda optimized for smartphones and tablets without creating multiple layout-files.

**Note:** You'll only need multiple layout files if you want to rearrange your views

The following android-developer pages should also be helpful: [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Designing for multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: Many confusion get clear after your explanation. Thanks a lot reVerse.